Add or Edit https binding?
I have an IIS 10 running several web applications under "Default Web Site".
I want to enable SSL binding for one of the web applications under "Default Web Site", say "dev-org-iis.domain.com/MyWebApp/Home.aspx"
I have a Org/Domain certificate installed in the server.
There already is an entry for https under Bindings for the "Default Web Site". And the bindings look like the screenshot

Screenshot
Should I "Edit" the https entry and choose the ssl certificate that i have created from the domain/organization
Or should i add another http binding using the "Add" button and choose my certificate in order to apply ssl for the specific web application?

as shown 8n the current point of view, the ssl will not work

HTTPS bindings can only be configured at site level. So if this site already has a proper HTTPS binding, you should use it instead of editing or adding a new one.
